# threading.Condition vs threading.Event

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, condition-variable

I have yet to find a clear explanation of the differences between `Condition` and `Event` classes in the **`threading`** module.  Is there a clear use case where one would be more helpful than the other?  All the examples I can find use a producer-consumer model as an example, where `queue.Queue` would be the more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Simply put, you use a Condition when threads are interested in waiting for something to become true, **and once its true, to have exclusive access to some shared resource.**

Whereas you use an Event when threads are just interested in waiting for something to become true.

In essence, Condition is an abstracted Event + Lock, but it gets more interesting when you consider that you can have several different Conditions over the same underlying lock. Thus you could have different Conditions describing the state of the underlying resource meaning you can wake workers that are only interested in particular states of the shared resource.

Answer (score 18):

Another subtle difference is that `Event`'s `set()` affects future calls of `wait()` (that is, subsequent calls of `wait()` will return `True` and won't block until `clear()` is called), whereas `Condition`'s `notify()` (or `notify_all()`) doesn't (subsequent calls of `wait()` will block till next call of `notify()`).

Comment: I don't feel like it's a difference per-se. Condition is a combination of a lock and an event (simplistically). You can say the event is auto-reset. But each call to `wait` should be prefaced with testing the "resource" you are using the condition for.