# Python Tkinter Threading - How to end / kill / stop thread when user closes GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

If I have a non for loop threaded task being run alongside tkinter such as `time.sleep(seconds)` how can I safely end the task before it has concluded, or, before the `time.sleep()` has ended.

If you run the program and click the button and then close the GUI window then `finished` will still print in the interpreter window a few seconds later.

Please note that in this case `time.sleep()` is just a placeholder for a long running non for loop function.

```
# python 3 imports
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import queue
import time

def center_app(toplevel):
    toplevel.update_idletasks()
    w = toplevel.winfo_screenwidth() - 20
    h = toplevel.winfo_screenheight() - 100
    size = tuple(int(Q) for Q in toplevel.geometry().split("+")[0].split("x"))
    toplevel.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (size + (w / 2 - size[0] / 2, h / 2 - size[1] / 2)))

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.USER_HAS_CLOSED_WINDOW)
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self, text = "*** Start Thread ***", font = ("Arial",25,"bold"), command = self.func_1)
        self.b1.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        center_app(self)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def USER_HAS_CLOSED_WINDOW(self, callback = None):
        print ("attempting to end thread")
        # end the running thread
        self.destroy()

    def func_1(self):
        self.b1.config(text = " Thread Running ")
        self.b1.update_idletasks()
        t = ThreadedFunction(self.queue).start()
        self.after(50, self.check_queue)

    def check_queue(self):
        try:
            x = self.queue.get(0) # check if threaded function is done
            self.b1.config(text = "*** Start Thread ***")
            self.b1.update_idletasks()
        except:
            self.after(50, self.check_queue)

class ThreadedFunction(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon = True)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(10) # how to end this if user closes GUI
        print ("finished")
        self.queue.put("result")

a = app()
a.mainloop()
```

I have made a function `USER_HAS_CLOSED_WINDOW` to catch the user closing the window, where I was thinking I would put something to end the running thread, but I'm not sure how.

I guess the other option is to put an appropriate `timeout` on the thread and use `.join()` somehow. But I'm not sure how to do that either

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you should use `Event` object and use `wait()` method and not `time.sleep` when you use thread that you want to interrupt.

Probably this can help you:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5205180
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38828735