# Interrupt a really long sleep function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, time, sleep

I need a way to interrupt a long `sleep` function, without splitting it into multiple `sleep(1)` or any shorter time. The way to stop it can be **any** possible way, including `threading`.

For deeper explanation, what i am trying to do is testing `sleep`'s limit, so I am writing a automate program repeat calling `sleep`. Catching all `OverflowError` raised by `sleep`.

What I've tried:

```py
from time import sleep
import threading
def test(x):
  try:
    sleep(x) #kill the thread or anyway to interrupt the sleep AFTER execution
  except:
    return 1
addigit = True
t = ""
while True:
  if addigit:
    t= t+"9"
  
  th = threading.Thread(target = test,args=(int(t),))
  print("running:"+t)
  ex = th.start()
  #threading.Lock.release() not working
  #th._stop()
  print(ex)
  if ex:
    if addigit:
      addigit = False
      print("len:"+len(t))
```

Notice that the code is incomplete, I only need the way of stopping `sleep` **right after** executed it. (I only need the exception raised by `sleep`, I don't want to wait for years to know the answer)

The *flag* or *stop statement check*(`if stop:exit`) way won't work, because they are executed after sleep.

Comment: The whole point of `sleep` is to pause your program so that it stops executing.  You'll need to use something else if you want to interrupt it.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I think this is a distinct question to the one you have linked. Here, the OP is asking explicitly about the `time.sleep` function. They're not looking for something which has the same effect as `time.sleep`. And there is an answer to that (multiprocessing or daemons). But I can't give it because the question is closed.

Comment: @Multihunter and if there were an answer to that question, it would be on the linked duplicate.  The question is exactly the same.  If you have an answer, leave it there.

Comment: @Mark Ransom There are answers AROUND it for this particular query. e.g. do they even need to kill the thread? They can use `join(1)` to check if it's thrown an error, and otherwise just leave it going. This would not be a solution to the linked question, but is a solution to this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead call wait() on a threading.Event object. It's what I typically do for a problem like this.

Here is an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38828735/14804613

Comment: i will try with that, looks like a good solution.